# Add SNS trigger to a specific lambda version using cloudformation stack

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am able to add SNS as an event source for my lambda function.But I am unable to add  SNS trigger to a specific lambda version ie to a qualified function name.

Here's my cloud formation snippet code:

```
LambdaCore:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
        S3Key: !Ref S3Key
      Description: Lambda Core with X-ray
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaCore
      Handler: !Ref LambdaCoreHandler
      MemorySize: '512'
      DeadLetterConfig:
        TargetArn: !GetAtt 
          - DeadLetterQueue
          - Arn
      Role: !GetAtt 
        - LambdaRoleForCore
        - Arn
      Runtime: java8
      Timeout: '300'
      TracingConfig:
        Mode: Active
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: !Ref SecurityGroups
        SubnetIds: !Ref Subnets
  Version:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Version
    DependsOn: 
      - LambdaCore
    Properties: 
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaCore
      Description: v1
 InputEventLambdaSubscription:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Subscription'
    DependsOn:
      - SNSTopic
      - LambdaCore
    Properties:
      Endpoint: !Ref
        - LambdaCore
        - Arn
      Protocol: lambda
      TopicArn: !Ref SNSTopic
 PermissionForSNSToInvokeCore:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    DependsOn:
      - LambdaCore
      - SNSTopic
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt 
        - LambdaCore
        - Arn
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: sns.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Ref SNSTopic
```

Comment: You should include a complete example of the CloudFormation template. This snippet doesn't really help because there are things about it that don't really make sense, like the `!Ref Version` within the `Version:` resource.

Comment: It's just a parameter. I have removed it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the subscription point to the version you need to use the version ARN in the subscription. The ARN of `AWS::Lambda::Version` will look just like a lambda ARN except that it includes the `:<version>` at the end.

A couple of other things.

1. You don't need to do `DependsOn` when the thing you are including in the dependency is a `Ref` or `GetAtt` in the resource.
2. The short form of `GetAtt` is a lot easier to look at an understand.

```
  LambdaCore:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
        S3Key: !Ref S3Key
      Description: Lambda Core with X-ray
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaCore
      Handler: !Ref LambdaCoreHandler
      MemorySize: '512'
      DeadLetterConfig:
        TargetArn: !GetAtt DeadLetterQueue.Arn
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRoleForCore.Arn
      Runtime: java8
      Timeout: '300'
      TracingConfig:
        Mode: Active
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: !Ref SecurityGroups
        SubnetIds: !Ref Subnets
  Version:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Version
    Properties: 
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaCore
      Description: v1
 InputEventLambdaSubscription:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Subscription'
    Properties:
      # this will return the ARN of the lambda with the version on it
      Endpoint: !Ref Version
      Protocol: lambda
      TopicArn: !Ref SNSTopic
 PermissionForSNSToInvokeCore:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaCore.Arn
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: sns.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Ref SNSTopic
```